# Again there are some holes in my plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a 3D plot of an expression but the the plot has some holes in it. I have asked a similar question before according to which I should adjust my `PlotRange`. I did that too. I have taken `PlotRange->All` but it didn't work. I also tried Full and Automatic for `PlotRange` but that didn't help also. Then I tried taking some values of plot range manually like `{-5,5}, {-0.1,0.1}, {-0.2,0.2}` etc. but either they don't fix the problem or alter the plot's shape. Firstly, I was taking `PlotPoints->100` for high-quality plots but then I changed its values to see what happens and when I chose `PlotPoints->20`, the appearance of holes was reduced but they were still there. I tried some other values of `PlotPoints` as well but they didn't disappear. Please tell me how to solve this issue?

```
\[Gamma] = x + I*y; 

z = 1; 

\[Theta] = Pi/4; 

m = 3; 

a = Sum[((1/(j!*l!))*Binomial[m, j]*Binomial[m, l]*Conjugate[z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]]]^j*(-2*\[Gamma] + z*Cos[\[Theta]])^j*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])^l*
       HypergeometricU[-l, 1 + j - l, (-2*\[Gamma] + z*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])]*(z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]])^l)/
      ((-2*\[Gamma] + z*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]))^l, {j, 0, m}, {l, 0, m}]/E^(2*Abs[\[Gamma] - z*Cos[\[Theta]]]^2)/
   (Pi*Sum[((1/(k!*l!))*(-1)^k*Binomial[m, k]*Binomial[m, l]*Conjugate[z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]]]^l*((-z)*Cos[\[Theta]])^l*(Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])^k*
       HypergeometricU[-k, 1 - k + l, (-z)*Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]^2]*(z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]])^k)/((-z)*Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^k, {l, 0, m}, {k, 0, m}]);

Plot3D[a, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

Comment: The holes appear, where a is getting complex, try to plot Re[a]

Comment: You can also try Plot3D[a //Chop,{x,...},{y,...}...]

Comment: Thanks. Using Chop solved it for me:)

Comment: @Andreas Can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it? :)

Comment: I also recommend that you use `Simplify` in the definition of `a` Look at `LeafCount /@ {a, a // Simplify}`

Comment: Code like this is unreadable. You should know that by not taking care of sharing reasonably formatted code in `InputForm`, you are alienating many experienced people that could otherwise help find a good answer.

Comment: @rhermans I copied this code from my mathematica notebook as it is and if you copy paste in in your worksheet, it will work just fine. I am not sure why it appears like this when I paste it here.

Comment: @Anaya well that is not enough, you may as well post compressed, uuencode or base64 coded string and it will still be true that there will be a way for Mathematica to interpret it. It remains that this is not human readable. This is a Q&A site for people not for a Kernel.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/10397)

Step-by-step:

1._ Make a copy of the cell containing the code to be posted
2._ Convert the copied cell to raw input form

3._ Choose Convert To > Raw InputForm from the Cell menu or from the contextual (right mouse clidk) menu

4._ Select the code and do a normal copy (do not use Copy As)
5._ Paste form the clipboard in the Mathematica.SE editor pane
6._ Delete the raw input form cell from the notebook.

Comment: @rhermans Okay now I get it. I was not aware of this method before.

Comment: @BobHanlon I tried simplifying it before plotting but it didn't work. Regarding the usage of LeafCount, can you elaborate because I don't know much about this command. I read the wolfram reference page about it but I didn't understand how to plot using this. :)

Comment: The `LeafCount` was used to reflect the different computation complexity of the expression before and after simplification, (i.e., `{44338, 6732}`). Whether or not simplified, using arbitrary precision rather than machine precision would also resolve your issue: `Plot3D[a, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 20, WorkingPrecision->15]` However, it is much more efficient when `Simplify` is included in the definition of `a`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you. It solved the problem:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function a shows in some regions of the x-y plane small imaginary parts.
You can get rid of them by modifying the plot command to

```
Plot3D[a//Chop, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},PlotRange->All]
```